# How to keep the the mini USB power secure?

Tags: power

I'm a total newbie here so please be gentle.

I'm thinking of using a Raspberry PI and a USB drive to make a [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage), but I'm worried about the way the PI gets its power. It looks like the power plug being <strike>mini</strike> micro USB could disconnect due to the slightest accidental wiggle.

Is the power secure? If not, can it be made more secure somehow?

Comment: **micro** usb, not mini.

Answer (score 1):

It is plenty secure the tolerances on the two mating surfaces (cable and socket) make for a very tight friction fit.  There are also small tangs that mate making the joint even more secure.

If you are having problems with the power cable coming dislodged, I would try another cable, as this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely agree with what steve said; this should not be a problem, and to try another cable.

But in some cases, it's not the cable's fault. For example, my Pi is in a 3d printed case. The combination of poorly fitted porthole and blocky plug on the wire made it fall out easily.

I would reccomend getting creative with some duct tape(assuming you have a case, you definitely don't wanna tape it directly to the Pi :) ).

But, first definitely try to find a cable that stays better,

Comment: I would argue that this is a problem with the design of the case and you would be better off modding the case or trimming the bulky plug. Than trying to jury rig it with tape.

Comment: True. However, I was just using what I had on-hand at the time; I didn't have anything to cut out the plastic of the case with, and I wasn't comfortable cutting into the plug of my power supply.